# Full path to the command

Tags: linux, bash

Why do I need to type the full path to the command?

```
# /sbin/ifconfig
```

I have a server where I can simply type ifconfig and on some other servers I have to type /sbin/ as well.
This is really annoying. How do I have consistent behavior?

Comment: As commented on in your question about su and bash, you should accept answers to some of your questions.  Just click the check mark next to the answer you think is best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your .bashrc to include /sbin in your search path.

```
PATH=/sbin:$PATH
export $PATH
```

This will add /sbin (and if you want to add it, /usr/sbin as well) to your command search path.

Comment: PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin # this line is already there. Do I edit the same line or add one more line as suggested by you? How do I get both /sbin and /usr/sbin?

Comment: Edit the line like PATH=/sbin:$PATH:$HOME/bin/ and don't forgot to #source .bashrc so that the new settings are available to current shell